# Can't pause AVPlayer with custom button

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, avplayer, avkit

I am trying to make a detailed view in swift, but I just can't figure out a way to pause the video with a custom button. And also when I go back to my list I can still hear the video playing in the background. Here is my code for the AVPlayer and for the button.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct Workdetail: View {

    var work: WorkoutDe
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    @State var isplaying = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                VideoPlayer(player: $player, work: work)
                    .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3.5)
     
                Butto(player: $player, isplaying: $isplaying)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct Butto : View {
                
    @Binding var player : AVPlayer
    @Binding var isplaying : Bool
               
    var body : some View {
         Button(action: {
             if self.isplaying {
                 self.player.pause()
                 self.isplaying = false
             } else {
                 self.player.play()
                 self.isplaying = true
             }
         }) {
             Image(systemName: self.isplaying ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                 .font(.title)
                 .foregroundColor(.white)
                 .padding(20)
         }
    }       
}

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
            
    var work : WorkoutDe
    @Binding var player : AVPlayer
    var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
        
    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: String(work.url)))
        
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
            player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            player.play()
        }
        player.play()
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func rewindVideo(notification: Notification) {
        playerLayer.player?.seek(to: .zero)
    }
    
    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) {
          
    }
}
```

The AVPlayer works but when I press the button nothing happens. The image for the button changes but the video won't stop playing. Can someone please explain to me how I can bind the button, because I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You work with different players in your sub views, try

```
 public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {

    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: String(work.url)))
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.player = player
    }
```

binding should update parent state, which will update Butto, so it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Asperi. I can see that now "Butto" pauses the video, but now the video doesn't load in and says "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior." I also edited the original post. Can you please help me with a suggestion to fix that problem?